# Calculate $\iint_\Omega \left(\sqrt{\frac xa}+\sqrt{\frac yb}\right)\,dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

**Problem**: Calculate $$\iint_\Omega \left(\sqrt{\frac xa}+\sqrt{\frac yb}\right)\,dxdy$$
where $\Omega$ is the domain bounded by the curve $\sqrt{\dfrac xa}+\sqrt{\dfrac yb} = 1$ and the coordinate axes.

**Solution**: Substitute $u=\sqrt{\dfrac xa}$ and $v=\sqrt{\dfrac yb}$, we have
$$\begin{cases} 0\le u\le 1\\ 0\le v\le 1- u \end{cases}$$
and since $x=au^2$ and $y=bv^2$, the Jacobian is $2au-2bv$. So the given integration become
$$
\begin{aligned}
I&=2\int^1_0\,du\int_0^{1-u}(u+v)(au-bv)\,dv\\
&=2\int^1_0\,du\int_0^{1-u}(au^2+auv-buv-bv^2)\,dv\\
&=2\int^1_0\left(au^2(1-u)+\frac{au^2(1-u)}{2}-\frac{bu(1-u)^2}{2}-\frac{b(1-u)^3}{3}\right)\,du\\
&=\frac{a-b}{4}.
\end{aligned}
$$

**Question**: But the answer to this problem is $\dfrac{2}{15}ab$. Can someone point out the mistake I've made in the above solution and give a right one? Thank you very much.

Comment: I think Jacobian is $$ \det \begin{pmatrix} 2au & 0 \\ 0 & 2bv \end{pmatrix} = 4abuv.$$

Answer (score 2):

The Jacobian is:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}  &\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}   \\
 \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} 
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
2au &0  \\
 0 & 2bv\end{vmatrix}=4abuv
$$
\begin{aligned}
I&=4ab\int^1_0\,du\int_0^{1-u}(u+v)uv\,dv\\
I&=-\frac{2ab}{15}
\end{aligned}

Comment: $I$ should be positive.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$ x=ar^2\cos^4\theta,y=br^2\sin^4\theta $$
and then the domain $\Omega$ becomes
$$ 0\le r\le1, 0\le\theta\le\frac\pi2. $$
Noting that
$$ \bigg|\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}  &\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}   \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} 
\end{matrix}\bigg|=abr^3\sin^3(2\theta), $$
one has
$$ \iint_\Omega \left(\sqrt{\frac xa}+\sqrt{\frac yb}\right)dxdy=\int_0^1\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}abr^4\sin^3(2\theta)d\theta dr=\frac{2ab}{15}.$$